# Cakephp-create a multi select form field

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, helper

I need to create a multi select form field using form helpers in cakephp.The values in the field will get populated from a table which had got a  HABTM to the current model.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: The best way to implement that is to use the Form Helper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your ctp file:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Category', array(
    'multiple' => 'multiple',
    'type' => 'select',
));
```

in your action:

```
$cats = $this->Category->find('all');
foreach ($cats as $category) {
    $categories[$category['Category']['id']] = $category['Category']['title'];
}
$this->set(compact('categories'));
```

Comment: It's better to use $categories = $this->Category->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'title')));

Comment: You are a god!!